# Play Framework 2.4 and the I18N support for dynamic added entites

Tags: playframework, internationalization, playframework-2.4

There are 2 collections: 'devices' and 'device types'. To create a device, we firstly need to choose its type (Tablet, Phone, Big Computer), which previously were added to a 'device types' collection on a separate page by some user. Device type' collection meant to be frequently updated.

In our project we have static message.en and message.es files. As I see a good way is to keep all I18N related stuff in one place - those files, but now I see only way to implement such functionality - keep all translations in a 'device type' collection (and same others) in separate fields like 'enName', 'esName', etc.

Is there any good way to provide the I18N support for such dynamic entities?

Comment: i18n of data added dynamically to your application should not be handled in `messages.**` files because you will not build your application each time a user adds a `deviceType` let's say in the backoffice of your application.

You should handle this in your model having for example a table of translations or with a `Map` in your model if you do not use a relational database.

It's more an application design problem than a Play Framework one.